# All Spring Boot Endpoints Result in 404 Not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to create a new springboot project, and whatever use a GET endpoint I try, I end up with error:

```
{
"timestamp": "2022-04-08T07:45:27.205+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/lol"}
```

this was from the endpoint `localhost:8080/lol`

My POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.chanSoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfOCRReader</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <name>pdfOCRReader</name>
    <description>pdf ocr</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-gcp.version>3.2.0</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-vision</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
              <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
              <type>pom</type>
              <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
              <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
              <version>25.1.0</version>
              <type>pom</type>
              <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My main class:

```
    package com.chansoft;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PdfOcrReaderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PdfOcrReaderApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

How my files are laid out:

[image]

For easier access, project is also on github:
https://github.com/14jchan/pdfOCRReader

Thank you guys so much and happy coding!

Comment: Did you use context-path or other path related varibles in application.properties? Also In @Requestmapping did you define anything on class?

Comment: @Gurkan Illeez What do you mean? My application.properties define my port as 8080, with all the db credentials, and the controller class has the RestController and RequestMapping annotations (see the github link I posted :))

Comment: Removed my answer given that it seems you have some other issues than the request mapping.

Comment: Got it working... it was a stupid JPA mistake where the column was misnamed. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Also for other projects, do ensure you have @ComponentScan enabled, sometimes the application does not register end points created in controller file (which is located in different package than source) :)